# angular form validation how to show error message from code

Tags: angularjs

I have a `validation.js` file that checks if a field is valid

```
exports.user = {
    username: function(input) {
        if (!input)
            return 'username is required'
        var min = 3
        var max = 10
        if (input.length < min)
            return 'username min of length is ' + min
        if (input.length > max)
            return 'username max of length is ' + max
        return null
    },
    password: function(input) {
        if (!input)
            return 'password is required'
        var min = 3
        var max = 10
        if (input.length < min)
            return 'password min of length is ' + min
        if (input.length > max)
            return 'password max of length is ' + max
        return null
    }

}
```

This is my sign in form (i just show the username field)

```
<div ng-if="showSignin" class="my-tab-pane">
    <form name="signin_form" action="{{signinServerUrl}}" method="POST">
        <div class="my-form-group">
            <label for="signin_username">Username:</label>
            <input ng-model="username" type="text" name="username" id="signin_username" placeholder="Enter Username" class="my-form-control" required username>

            <div ng-show="signin_form.$submitted || signin_form.username.$touched">
                <div ng-show="signin_form.username.$error.required">Tell us your username. </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is my custom validation:

```
var app = angular.module('custom_validation');
var helper = require('../helper.js')

app.directive('username', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$validators.username = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
                if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
                    return false; //required
                }

                var msg = helper.validation.username(username)
                if (msg)
                    return false
                return true
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Notice that my validation.js file also handles `required`, so I would like to use only my `custom_validation`. But it can only return `true` `false` value. How can I pass along the error message?

I will probably be using `ng-message` like

```
<div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>
```

But the error message is still not from my `validation.js`

The reason I want to encapsulate validation is that,

the UI implementor should not worry about if a field is `required` or not, for example. It should be as simple as checking an input and getting the error message.

Also, The file is reused in my server code, for example (Server mongodb code)

```
UserSchema.pre('save', true, function(next, done) {
    var self = this //in case inside a callback
    var msg = helper.validation.user.username(self.username)
    if (msg) {
        self.invalidate('username', msg)
        done(helper.getValidationError(msg))
    }
    else
        done()
    next()
})
```

Comment: why don't you save msg in a scope veriable and then use it in the view

Comment: because i want to sorta keep it 'inside' the validation mechanism. Otherwise I have to `$watch` the input manually

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the approach you're taking. Validation.js is doing multiple validations in one function.  This forces clients of the custom validation code to interpret what actually went wrong. Instead, I suggest creating custom $validators functions. Also, to keep the separation of concerns between presentation and validation, ensure that the error messages are not tied to validation function.

Comment: @pixelbits I saw your deleted answer just now and maybe my question is not clear for you. the validation is kinda `business logic` and should be separated from the UI part.

Comment: `validation.js` is well encapsulated and the UI implementor should not worry about if a field is `required` or not, for example.

Comment: "validation logic is kinda business logic and should be separated from the UI part"  I agree, but I think your approach goes against this.

Comment: @pixelbits The client does not need to know what went wrong. It just need to get the message and display it. So the error message has to be from a function, not hard coded.

Comment: Why you are using directive for validation?Is there any specific requirement?

Comment: Actually where are you using the `username` directive in the given example?

Comment: What validation you want for username?

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN yes, because the angular default validators does not meet my other needs

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN in `username` HTML field. I just updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's javsacript, you can create a custom field in `$error`

```
var msg = helper.validation.username(username)
ctrl.$error.usernameMessage = msg;
if (msg)
    return false
return true
```

and use it later in UI

```
<div ng-show="signin_form.username.$error.username">
     {{signin_form.username.$error.usernameMessage}}
</div>
```

Note that I changed the field in `ng-show` to match your new validator
Working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/P78hyxhQqmXydByDI8Ah?p=preview)

**EDIT**
Requiring `ngModel` in the directive gives access to the `ng-model` controller of `input` where the directive is applied (`ctrl` parameter of link function). Actually it is same as `$scope.signin_form.username` (here `username` stands for the variable in scope bound to `ngModel`) of the `MainCtrl` so you can access it either way. As the `username` directive doesn't isolate its scope, inside the link function `scope.signin_form` gives access to the form in `MainCtrl`'s `$scope` due to prototypal inheritance. But with such notation you're forced to hardcode the name of the form and field in the directive. So it's a correct thing to get access via `ng-model` since there might be multiple fields in the form with applied `username` directive. In the template however you can only access the form via `$scope` of `MainCtrl`, thus we use `{{signin_form.username.$error.usernameMessage}}`

Comment: is `ctrl` the same as `signin_form` in html?

Comment: @OMGPOP I updated the question. Actually had to reach out to the form via the out scope

Comment: it's working. Can you explain more about ctrl and scope? is ctrl the input widget or controller? Also is it possible to be less wordy?

Comment: @OMGPOP well it was confusing even for me, actually the original one works, so i reverted to `ctrl` and provided explanation. What do you mean by "wordy"?

Comment: I decided to directly use scope.message = 'xxx' in code, and `{{message}}` in html

Comment: So the `ctrl` argument is the same as `signin_form`, not `signin_form.username`?

Comment: Please look into this question. The `ctrl` is not working but `scope` works.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31487733/angular-why-is-my-field-invalid/31487756#31487756